Excel with Multiple Digital Signature in one Sheet
How can I protect my digital signature in an Excel file that has many users and different digital signatures? Currently, anyone can open and alter different signatures in the Excel file. Is there a way to put a password on each digital signature to protect them individually?
For now my current setup is overall password on excel only the drop down to put signature on a certain documents but all user can put a different signature.
Thank you,

Can you clarify what you mean by digital signature? It's sounds like you're actually talking about a digitized analog signature, i.e. a digitized version of someone's hand-written signature.
